# STRAFTER SPARQL 1.1 function in Virtuoso

Tags: rdf, sparql, virtuoso

Does `STRAFTER` from SPARQL 1.1 work in Virtuoso (version 6.04 June 2012 build)?

Trying

```
PREFIX qb:  <http://purl.org/linked-data/cube#>
PREFIX iodp: <http://data.oceandrilling.org/core/1/>
PREFIX sdmx-dimension:  <http://purl.org/linked-data/sdmx/2009/dimension#>
SELECT ?p (strafter(str(?p), "http://data.oceandrilling.org/janus/") AS ?pshort)
FROM <http://data.oceandrilling.org/janus/>
WHERE {
   <http://data.oceandrilling.org/janus/ngr_section201_1226> qb:observation ?observation .
   ?observation ?p ?o .
   FILTER (regex(?p, "janus")) .
   FILTER (!regex(?p, "leg")) .
   FILTER (!regex(?p, "site")) .
   FILTER (datatype(?o) = <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#decimal>) .
}
```

at http://data.oceandrilling.org/sparql throws a SPARQL compile error.

Answer (score 3):

No it does not support straft, you will need build 6.1.5 [see the release notes](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VOSNews#SPARQL%20and%20RDF).